# Deriving probability if it contains its own probability (and its derivative)

Tags: probability

I need to solve the following equation to obtain an expression for the probability, an approximation would be accceptable if no exact solution is possible:

$$\text{Prob}\left(y_1\leq y_2\right)=\text{Prob}\left(\frac{a}{x_1}-\frac{a}{x_2}<\frac{1-2\text{Prob}\left(y_1\leq y_2\right)}{\frac{\partial \text{Prob}\left(y_1\leq y_2\right)}{\partial y_2}}\right)$$

$a$ is some constant, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are random variables with known properties, same mean but different variances, the other properties can be flexible (symmetric, normal, etc.).

For context: I am optimizing a profit function (that's what we do in economics), where the profits depend on your own decision variable ($y_i$) and that of a competitor $y_{3-i}$ and who has the lower value will get the profits. What I get is
$$y_1=\frac{a}{x_1}+\frac{\text{Prob}\left(y_1\leq y_2\right)}{\frac{\partial \text{Prob}\left(y_1\leq y_2\right)}{\partial y_2}}$$
$$y_2=\frac{a}{x_2}+\frac{1-\text{Prob}\left(y_1\leq y_2\right)}{\frac{\partial \text{Prob}\left(y_1\leq y_2\right)}{\partial y_2}}$$

Here $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two noisy signals that are independent of each other and have the same mean but different variances. I can adjust properties of the signals to suit the ability to obtain a solution.

I can now insert for $y_1\leq y_2$ and obtain the initial equation.

I am now interested in obtaining $\text{Prob}\left(y_1\leq y_2\right)$ to get a full solution to my problem for $y_i$. Is there any way to get a solution?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Yes, even apart from users' quality standards I am really curious how you arrived at this strange equation. I have never seen something like this and would like to know in what context it showed up.